# PHP Form , session data not being stored

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

we are working with php session data, but the data is not being stored in the database

login.php

```
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<form action = "Customer.php" method = "POST">
 Customer Name:<input type = "text" name="customerName">
 <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
</form>
```

Customer.php

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
#include("Connection.php);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $name = $_POST['customerName']; 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $name; 
} 
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    echo "Hello {$_SESSION['user']}, welcome to starbucks!"; 
}
else
{
    echo "walang tao";
    $sql="INSERT INTO  `customer`.`people` ('ID', `NAME`) VALUES ('','$name')";
    mysql_query($sql);
?>
<a href = "logout.php">Logout</a>
```

and logout.php

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();

?>

<a href = "index.php">Click me to return to login </a>
```

please tell me what's wrong

Comment: You should maybe remove the # in #include("Connection.php);

Comment: ad some basic debugging to the query.

Comment: Is there a difference in saving the data to mysql when it is retrieved from session vs specified right in the code as string literals?

Comment: also, you missing a } after mysql_query($sql);

Comment: you're doing an insert inside of the condition of no session data, how do you expect that to get saved? or even it's outside of that `else` block, there is still no session data because you're depending on `isset($_POST['submit'])` to get something assigned to your session variable.

Comment: and then how do I fix that? where should I place the query

Comment: inside where you check for POST, so you only save if there's a submitted data. then fix your permissions with mysql..and organize your code a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

try displaying the mysql_error and see what the problem is

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks but it gave this error INSERT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'people

Comment: You have a permissions problem with mysql. Check your privileges!